# Run konsole script opening php script from python

Tags: scripts, batch, konsole

I've written a python script, which runs, and upon closure I want it to open a shell script, that opens a php script.

1. Python script directory: `/home/user/test/a` named: `python1.py`
2. Shell script directory: `/home/user/test/b` named: `konsole1.sh`
3. Php script directory: `/home/user/test/c` named: `php1.php`

My commands to run the scripts manually in the commandline are:

1.

```
cd /home/user/test/a/
#!/home/user/test/a/ python
python python1.py
```

iii) yes, after my path consisting of a combination of brute force and educated guesses, I learned that that order worked, as you can see I have not been capable to apply efficiency nor elegance yet. But I just learned that that line is indeed not necessary, thank you :)

2.

```
? not relevant/not the goal
```

i) Since the goal is not to run/open a .sh script from commandline, but to build a .sh script which runs in konsole. How I should call that .sh script from python is a secondary problem which I will tackle when the time comes. And to me, there appears to be a significant difference between simply pasting executable commands in a .sh and actually have a .sh execute those commands.

3.

```
cd /home/users/test/
php php1.php
```

What I would love to know is what I need to write in the script konsole1.sh so that when I double click it, it will open konsole and execute the commands given at 3.

I've tried a multitude of codes but I can't seem to nail or get the syntax correct at all, google turned out not to be my friend on this one, it seems too trivial.

My best/**an** attempt so far has been for konsole1.sh:

```
konsole --hold -e cd /home/user/test/c/
user@host:~$ php php1.php
```

ii) Yes desperate times yielded desperate attemts, that combined with a lack of knowledge was acknowledged with the "an", by the way it was 1 of many attempts, which I think, like this one, could raise more questions than answers, hence I did not post 20 different tries, but did not want to show no attempt at all.

And it just opens Konsole upon double-clicking, but does not excecute anything.

iv) because of 3 factors:

1. Directly calling the php script from python yielded a different problem which I have not been able to solve so far
2. I expect to have to glue multiple different scripts from different languages along to reach my goal, as well as a requirement to start from a konsole-script/shell-script to initiate my process.
3. Creating a simple konsole script would appear to be a rudimentary basic for my skillset.

If you have any further questions please let me know :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify. i) What is "2. ? not relevant"? Your whole question seems to be about ii) Do you actually have the prompt (`@user@host:~$`) in the shell script? iii) Do you really run `#!/home/user/test/a/ python` on the commandline? iv) Why aren't you just running the php script directly? What's the point of python -> shell -> php? Please [edit] and clarify what you are trying to do and why you are taking such a complex route for it.